# Update sqlite3 in docker image

Tags: python, docker, sqlite

I'm checking my sqlite3 version using:

```
python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
```

on my local machine, this prompts me 3.41.1. However, once I build my docker image if I do:

```
sudo docker exec -t <docker_image_number> python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
```

I obtain 3.34.1.

To build the docker I'm running from python:3.9.3. I have read that sqlite3 is a library from python itself, that is updated depending on the python version/the version they used for compiling. I have tried even python:3.16.0, but still I get 3.34.1. I would like to have at least sqlite3 3.35. How can I update this library? For my docker I do a `RUN apt-get update` and a `RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt`, but requirements is a freeze of my conda library where sqlite3 is 3.41.1

```
FROM python:3.9.3

# from compose args
ARG BITBUCKET_APP_PASS 

# Variable arguments
WORKDIR /code

#Install requirements
#COPY ./.env ./.env
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

#Copy code into the container
COPY ./django_app/ /code/app/src/
COPY ./init_app_in_docker.sh /code/app/src/init_app_in_docker.sh
COPY ./.env ./code/app/src/.env

#Start the app
WORKDIR /code/app/src/
CMD ./init_app_in_docker.sh
```

Comment: Show us the dockerfile

Comment: there you have!

Comment: There isn't a Python 3.16 so I have no idea how you tried that. In any case, it's baked into the python distribution so I don't think you can easily bump the version. Why do you need a newer version?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I tried 3.9.16 and 3.11. I need it because I need something specific in django using sqlite that is only avalaible 3.35+ sqlite version. Otherwise I need to mount a psotgresql docker... but anyway, I'll go for that. Nontheless, I was curious too for such solution.

Comment: Your core issue is that the [Docker Hub `python` images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) are all built on Debian, but the newest [packaged SQLite in a stable Debian release](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/sqlite3) is 3.34.1.

Comment: ok that was the point... Thank you very much, I didn't know how to find out why I had that version

Comment: @DavidMaze can you make that an answer if that's solving the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a clean recipe for getting a newer version.  In principle you could attempt to install packages from a newer (unreleased) Debian version, but this can quickly run into trouble, or build your own image based on Ubuntu (which releases more often).

Answer (score 0):

I am building a flask application which required sqlite3 version to be 3.35+ as well.
For my docker image, I am using python 3.11, and that brings sqlite3 version 3.40 with it which works for me.
These are the first lines from the Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install pip==21.3.1
```

I downgraded my pip to 21.3.1 to access some libraries which are not indexed in higher versions, feel free to disregard that.